# Good Auto-generation of POD from a Schema?

Tags: c++, schema, protocol-buffers, auto-generate

All,

Does anyone know of a tool that can create vanilla POD-like C++ structures from a Schema description?

Important qualities are:

- reasonable to use as "first class citizens" inside of the code.
- aggregates are packed just like native arrays.
- other, interactive language support ( i.e. Python or Matlab. )

  - use of each languages native-types a plus.
- default and valid values defined and used.

Nice to haves are:

- no implicit use of the heap ( explicit through the schema would be okay )
- very light API ( no API is okay; element-name accessors-by-reference are okay; get_foo/set_foo is tolerable but discouraged. )

I've played with Google Protocol-Buffers briefly.  It appears that a "repeated" & "packed" primitive satisfies one of my conditions, but the API is not designed for this use.

Context:  I'm looking to write portable, high-performance code, ( thus must of my requirements, ) where intermediate products can be loaded / saved and then inspected and manipulated by proper analysis / scripting languages.  The data structures are always changing, thus needing a way to auto-generate the classes for all languages involved.

Comment: I think I'm looking for the same thing...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073930/conversion-between-c-structs-c-pod-and-google-protobufs

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558881/plain-struct-from-protocol-buffer-message